# Changing from asp to PHP - server?

Tags: linux, php, iis, asp

I've been developing ASP for quite a while using IIS and hosting it on an NT-server (which has 2 IPs).
Since a few months I'm coding in PHP (using xampp on Windows) and would also like to change my webhosting stuff from ASP to PHP.

I'm thinking about keeping my NT-server and simply install xampp on it (using my 2nd IP) so that I can keep my older ASP pages and also the emailserver + all the domain hosting.

My question: do you think it's a good idea running xampp (for PHP) on the NT-server (performance-wise)? would there be any disadvantage?

or should I better go for a Linux server? (I'm not familiar with that at all).

Comment: Are you really running NT4?

Comment: sorry i meant Windows 2003 server .. :/

Comment: Can you go back and edit all the questions you've raised with 'NT' in them please!

Answer (score 1):

Given how old asp is, how long it was replaced and how long NT4 drivers dont exist anymore you are better off buying a smartphone and run your web server on that. Seriously. Probably an outdated phone has 10 times the processing power of your NT server.

NT is so outdated this has tobe a fake. IIS waht? 2.0? 3.0?

I suggest starting at this end. REading a magazine about current technology may help terrifically. You are stuck.. hm... 1995?

Comment: NT4 got as up to IIS4.0 with the option pack installed.

Comment: Now, let's be fair. NT4 was state-of-the-art until February 2000 or so.

Comment: Yes. WIndows 3.1 also was state of the art at ONE point ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should do whatever you can to get on a more modern operating system that offers security updates and will have people around who can support it.  If you're considering a switch to Linux you have to consider the time involved in learning how to implement all the features your current NT server offered your company within Linux, or investing in two new systems.  Alternatively, you could purchase a new system and use virtual machines to have both a Windows domain controller and a Linux webserver and I'm sure it will still outperform any NT-era hardware.

Comment: I second the virtual machine idea, if the budget is at all possible to purchase a new server and put the free [VMware vSphere Hypervisor](http://www.vmware.com/support/product-support/vsphere-hypervisor.html) on it.  You can clone your existing NT machine into a virtual machine and then gradually move things over to either a linux virtual machine or a Windows 2008 R2 virtual machine.  If you don't have the budget for Windows, at least move your web hosting to a linux machine - I suggest Ubuntu and get help [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/)