# Should I switch from Windows Server 2003 to Linux when I switch from ASP to PHP?

Tags: windows-server-2003, php, asp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing from asp to PHP - server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/271206/changing-from-asp-to-php-server)

I've been developing ASP for quite a while using IIS/Windows Server 2003. A few months ago I started coding in PHP (using XAMPP on Windows) and would also like to port all my webhosting stuff from ASP to PHP from time to time.

I'm thinking about keeping my Windows Server and simply installing XAMPP on it so that I can keep my older ASP pages and also the emailserver + all the current domain hosting.

My question: do you think it's a good idea running XAMPP (for PHP) on the Windows server performance-wise? Would there be any disadvantage?

Should I switch to a Linux server, which I am not familiar with at all?

Answer (score 1):

Performance-wise, you'll be fine. Use the OS you're familiar with. Personally I'm not a huge fan of pre-packaged mini-distros like xampp, but that's only tangentially relevant.